# Convert XML to String using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Need to convert the XML to String

Input XML:

```
<Texts>
<text>123</text>
<text>456</text>
<text>789</text>
</Texts>
```

Output String

```
T1=123&T2=456&T3=789
```

I'm using following XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="Texts">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="concat" select="text" />
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text" mode="concat">
    <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()"/>
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
        <xsl:text>P($position)=</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
        <xsl:text></xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="position() = last()"> 
    <xsl:text>&amp;P$position=</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Let me know whats wrong. The elements text in XML can be any number

Comment: It's much easier if *you* let *us* know what's wrong! :P What output are you getting?

Comment: This is the output i got          P($position)=123456789&P$position=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Texts/text" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('P', position(), '=', .)" />
    <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">&amp;</xsl:if>
  </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

outputs

```
P1=123&P2=456&P3=789
```

Note that you actually should use URL encoding on the values of each `<text>`, but that's not built into XSLT 1.0 (but 2.0 has a function for it).

If you are dealing with number values you should be fine, if not you should look for ways to get a URL encoding function into your stylesheet. There are several ways to extend XSLT with external functions, it depends on your XSLT engine which one applies to you.

Comment: For what it's worth, EXSLT has the function [`str:encode-uri`](http://exslt.org/str/functions/encode-uri/index.html) which some XSLT 1.0 processors support.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's easier to use `xsl:for-each`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="Texts/text">
            <xsl:if test="position() != 1">&amp;</xsl:if>T<xsl:value-of select="position()" />=<xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That could be greatly simplified by using `concat()`. Well. It could be simplified a little. :)

Comment: My XSLT-jitsu is rusty =)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest/fastest way to do it is (if you have in XPath 2):

```
 string-join(//text / concat("T", position(), "=", .), "&")
```

Or better, if you actually need it url encoded, and put it verbatim in a XSLT:

```
 string-join(//text / concat("T", position(), "=", encode-for-uri(.)), "&amp;")
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in XPath 2.0 (and therefore XSLT 2.0) like this:

```
string-join(
  for $i in 1 to count(//text) 
    return concat('T', $i, '=', (//text)[$i]), 
  '&')
```